# is there a way to display message box maximum of 5 times?

Tags: c#, while-loop, messagebox

I want my while loop to use a message box to ask a question maximum 5 times.

when I run it, im asked once and when I select yes 5 new forms open.

how do I fix this loop to prevent the message box from asking user yes or no more than 5 times, and how to prevent 5 forms opening when yes I selected once?

my code

```
 private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int maxAddDriver = 5;
        int addDriver = 0;

        DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        Hide();

        while (addDriver < maxAddDriver && answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            addDriver++;

            Hide();

            new frmAdditionalDriver().Show();


            //answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?",
            //    "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }


        new frmInsurancePolicy().ShowDialog();

        Show();
    }
```

Comment: _maxAddDriver_ and _addDriver_ should be moved outside the event handler to a form level. Then you should change your while loop to a simple if

Comment: However your question is unclear. You want to show the _frmAdditionalDriver_ form once when you press the button but if you reach 5 clicks on that button you would stop to show the form? And what you want to do with _frmInsurancePolicy_ when you reach the fifth click?

Comment: I want to show frmInsurancePolicy if the answer is no or if the user has selected yes 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
Move maxAddDriver and addDriver to outside of button click so they will not be reset each time the button is clicked and retain previous clicked count.

```
int maxAddDriver = 5;
int addDriver = 0;

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // already displayed message box 5 times, so just display insurance policy dialog
        if (this.addDriver == this.maxAddDriver)
        {
            new frmInsurancePolicy().ShowDialog();
        }

        var answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?", "Info",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        Hide();
        this.addDriver++;

        if (answer == DialogResult.Yes && this.addDriver < this.maxAddDriver)
        {
            new frmAdditionalDriver().Show();
        }
        Show();
    }
```

Comment: You can do better. Why asking if you want to add a new driver if you can't?

Comment: @Steve, are you talking about message box display after 5th time? I agree that I overlooked this part in the post => prevent the message box from asking user yes or no more than 5 times